# How to access NULL value

Tags: java, nullreferenceexception

```
while(i<word.length)
{
   ans=swn.extract(word[i], pos[i]);
   if(ans== null)
        polarvalue[i]= " ";
   else
        polarvalue[i]=ans;
   i++;
   System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Hi, Friends this is my code and the swn.extracts a value which can be null so the ANS contains the null value and when i try to access it gives NULlPOinterException is there any way that i can check the NULL value and change it to any other value.? But if i removes the whole If..else section it gives no error and prints the "NULL" in the output...

Comment: If i remove the whole If..else section then the code prints the null value..

Comment: Please show *exactly* where the exception occurs. It could be due to `word`, `swn`, `pos` or `polarvalue` being null.

Comment: The ans contains the null value from the method EXTRACT and i am okay with it. and i want to access it.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace as @JonSkeet has said

Comment: Please answer my question, or ideally change your code to provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @david99world i am quite new here...so how to do stack trace.

Comment: "and i want to access it", are you trying to acces a null value? obviously, you can't...

Comment: Are you running this through Eclipse or Netbeans etc?  You should have an exception in your console if you are getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: Most likely your variable `polarvalue` is null.

Comment: Simple thumb rule. If you are going to place a 'dot' next to any variable, just add a null check for that variable before doing so.

Comment: @logoff actully i want to change the value of that NULL to a " " ..in my code.

Comment: @HarshilShah `if(ans == null) { ans = " ";}`? but anyway it has no sense for me. you are assigning it well in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i remove the whole If..else section then the code prints the null
>   value.

If above is true, mean your `polarvalue[]` array is `null` and you are trying to assigned the `ith` position value by using `polarvalue[i]` that's way, it's throwing null pointer exception.
Do a null check of `polarvalue[]` array before assigned.

Your code is dangerous, It seems it can throw `NPE` every where  like

```
while(i<word.length)   // do a null check
ans=swn.extract(word[i], pos[i]);  // do a null check
polarvalue[i]= " ";  // do a null check
polarvalue[i]=ans;  // do a null check
```

Do a null check it will take few minutes but reduce your most valuable time .